# Isometric transformation

Tags: geometry, reflection, isometry

If $S$ belongs to the line $p$, prove that each of the isometrics $\rho_{S,\omega}$ ◦ $ \sigma_p$ and $ \sigma_p$ ◦ $\rho_{S,\omega}$ should be axial reflection.

Can anyone please help me with this proof?

Answer (score 0):

HINT.

The points of line $p_1=\rho_{S,\omega/2}(p)$ are fixed points under $\rho_{S,\omega} \circ \sigma_p$, while the points of line $p_2=\rho_{S,-\omega/2}(p)$ are fixed points under $ \sigma_p\circ\rho_{S,\omega}$.